# Accessing WordPress network installation in MAMP over LAN

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp, lan

I have a WordPress network installed locally and use MAMP Pro to run a server. I would like to view all the sites from another computer or device in the same LAN.

Is there a clean and simple way to do this?

I have MAMP setup so that it goes the a folder called Sites. In that folder each project has its own folder. Some projects are just simple HTML and CSS. I can view them just fine from my iPad. One project is a WordPress installation, and I can't load that folder. My guess is it's something about MySQL and a different IP trying to access it.

Comment: add the site's hostname(s)+ip to your local machine's hosts file, then simply hit that hostname in the browser?

Comment: It doesn't work. Simple html files visible. Put as soon as I try to access the "WordPress folder" it doesn't load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to making this work is changing your WordPress and Site URLs to your IP address + MAMP port in the WordPress Dashboard in Settings > General.

For example, if those URLs are currently `localhost`, you would instead set them to `mysite.local:8888`.

Just remember to change those URLs back to their correct values if/when you move your WordPress installation to another server.

Comment: Another potential solution to this problem is to add the following to your wp-config.php file:

`define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`, which will change the site URL and home values to be whatever URL was used to access the site.

Answer (score 4):

the main issue is because wordpress use the server address from database, wordpress use the root url from the database option named `home` and `siteurl` so if you try access wordpress outside their computer it may get the incorrect path for css and javascript.

if you want to get correct path without doing redirect, you can defining the dynamic root url under `wp-config.php`

add this script below the `define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');`

```
/**
 * get home url from absolute path
 * @return string url to main site
 * hello@lafif.me
 */
function get_dynamic_home_url(){
    $base_dir  = ABSPATH; // Absolute path
    $doc_root  = preg_replace("!${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}$!", '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    $base_url  = preg_replace("!^${doc_root}!", '', $base_dir);
    $protocol  = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https';
    $port      = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $disp_port = ($protocol == 'http' && $port == 80 || $protocol == 'https' && $port == 443) ? '' : ":$port";
    $domain    = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $home_url  = "${protocol}://${domain}${disp_port}${base_url}";

    return $home_url;
}
$url = get_dynamic_home_url();
define('WP_SITEURL', $url);
define('WP_HOME', $url);
```